# SQL - Getting data from a column if it meets a condition from another column

Tags: sql, database, case, bigdata

So I have a dataset that looks something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiBbi.png)

I need to get the names of the Associate who stowed the TRID BUT ONLY if the same TRID has been Picked as well on a different day. So in essence, ignore the TRIDs that have not been picked yet.

I have a basic query so far to get the TRIDs that have been picked but I need the Associates that stowed them.

Select TRID From Data
Where Status = 'Picked'

But can't figure out how to get the Associates that stowed them.

Comment: From the data, it seems it can stowed multiple times, right.

Comment: `select distinct mt.* from my_table mt where mt.status='stowed' and exists(select mt1.id from my_table mt1 where mt1.id=mt.id and mt1.status='picked')` this is using subquery

Comment: And using self join `select distinct mt1.* From my_table mt1 inner join my_table mt2 on mt1.id=mt2.id where mt1.status='stowed' and mt2.status='picked'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a sub-query to filter out the TRIDs which is picked already and pass those IDs to the whole data to get the associates who stowed it.

```
select associate 
from data 
where TRID in (select TRID from data where Status = 'Picked')
and Status = 'stowed'
```

Comment: This should work. Let me try this. Thank you!